# C++ to Java - OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to "port" an OpenCV C++ program to Java, but the syntax is quite different.

I can't find the Java OpenCV equivalents of:

```
img_bw.at<uchar>(j,i);
boundingRect();
vector.push_back(Point(i,j)); // the Point part
```

Also, how to reserve space in a Vector?

Comment: usually it is a bad idea, to port opencv c++ code to java literally. what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to find the Java equivalents for openCV C++ code. You just have to dig through the internet. A lot of it is already on StackOverflow.

A vector is essentially a Matrix. So `Mat` is god place to look. `MatOfPoint` should be your vector equivalent, which is just a matrix with points. There are many more MatOf-type objects.

This code is not semantically equivalent (as I don't know C++), but to give you an idea where to go from here:

```
mat.get(row, col); // returns pixel info as a double[]
Imgproc.boundingRect(matOfpoint); // returns a Rectangle that wraps the points in this matrix
matOfpoint.push_back(otherMatOfPoint); // pushes points from otherMatOfPoint to the matOfPoint matrix
```

Comment: One more problem, img_bw.at<uchar>(j,i); returns an int, as the image is grayscale, how to do the same in Java?

Comment: `img_bw.at<uchar>(j,i)` is the same as `mat.get(j,i)` as I already stated in my answer. If you have a grayscale image then you just get a `double[]` with 1 entry.